# Equilibrium in difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving this system of difference equations:

$$\begin{cases} x_{t+1}=2x_t+y_t\\ y_{t+1}=x_t+2y_t\end{cases}$$

I am using Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors to find the solution and I had a general questions when facing difference equations. When solving differential equations, I would need to solve the following to find the solution:[image]

What should I put in the last vector to find the solution provided here we do not have a fixed point as equilibrium?

Comment: Every $(z,-z)$ is an equilibrium point. Yes "equilbrium" means that $(x_{t+1},y_{t+1})=(x_t,y_t)$ (if this is your question...).

Comment: ok so if there is no fixed point for equilibrium what should I add in the solution as equilibrium? for differential equations like $\dot y$ I add the equilibrium vector.

Comment: Sorry but your comment is not phrased in a langage I can understand. "no fixed point for equilibrium" ?? "add in the solution as equilibrium" ?? "add the equilibrium vector" ??

Comment: i edited my question now.

Comment: In ODEs, the general solution of $x'=Ax$ is in terms of $e^{At}$. In difference equations, the general solution of $x_{n+1}=Ax$ is in terms of $A^n$. If $A=PJP^{-1}$ is a Jordan decomposition (a diagonalization, in the diagonalizable case), then $A^n=P J^n P^{-1}$, just like how $e^{At}=P e^{Jt} P^{-1}$ in the differential equations context. One would usually use the difference equation version to prove the differential equation version (using a power series).

Comment: "provided here we do not have a fixed point as equilibrium" ?? Are you aware that "fixed point" and "equilibrium" are actually synonymous? In the discrete example in your question, fixed points/equilibria solve $(x_{t+1},y_{t+1})=(x_t,y_t)$, which reduces to $x_t+y_t=0$. Hence my **first** comment.